How to retrieve the matching @Produces content type in a resource method?
I have a resource method that can produce JSON-LD (preferred option) or JSON so I used the following annotation:
@Produces({MEDIA_TYPE_JSON_LD + "; qs=1", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; qs=0.5"})

Now I want to produce a result that depends on the matching content type.
Is there a way to know which content type was matched?
If I had no quality factors I could re-create the matching process using:
List<Variant> variants = 
  Variant.mediaTypes(MediaType.valueOf(MEDIA_TYPE_JSON_LD),
  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).build();
Variant selectedVariant = request.selectVariant(variants);
String matchedContentType = selectedVariant.getMediaType().toString();

but this does not work with source quality factors (qs).
